# Angular 2 with bootstrap display every 3 items dynamically in a column

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular5 with bootstrap3, 
In the component I have some data that looks like this

```
items = [
  { name: 'item1' },
  { name: 'item2' },
  { name: 'item3' }
  ...
  { name: 'item14' }
  ...
]
```

In the template, I need to create bootstrap columns in a dynamic way, so each created column will contain only 3 items, but for the last column (4th column), it will contain the rest.

so something like this (in this order):

```
item1   item4   item7   item10
item2   item5   item8   item11
item3   item6   item9   item12
                        item13
                        item14
                        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function for this:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="items.slice(0, 3)">
         Your item template for the first column
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="items.slice(3, 6)">
         Your item template for the second column
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="items.slice(6, 9)">
         Your item template for the third column
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="items.slice(9)">
         Your item template for the rest
    </div>
</div>
```